# Not finding any forms with mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

This website is "https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login"

I am looking for a form with

```
browser.select_form(nr=0)
```

however its telling me no form matching nr 0, so I assume it isn't picking up the form, and so I print out the response, and it's the same response I get on my browser as well. It seams the form is being loaded via Javascript. Is there any way for mechanize to work around this?

by the way, I have tried looping through and printing the form labels but I get nothing, so that confirms that it is not picking up any forms.

Comment: Not horribly familiar with mechanize, but a lot of these toolsets suffer from this problem. An alternative that I have used in the past is to instead use the DOM of a browser like IE that has a javascript engine built in.